# Microsoft Office 2016 update button missing

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I just installed MS Office 2016 Pro Plus edition and its build version is 16.0.4312.1000. The problem is that on File -> Account page the update buttons/options are not present below the "About" button. As much as I can remember, the last office 2016 installation I had sometime ago had those options through which I used to update to latest build. How can I get those back? Is there some edition difference?

Note: I tried installing updates through Windows Update. Some updates were installed but the build version was the same!

Comment: Maybe there aren't any updates available...

Comment: Are you signed into the app for sure ??

Answer (score 4):

As stated from the [Microsoft Office Support Site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Install-Office-updates-2ab296f3-7f03-43a2-8e50-46de917611c5):

> If Update Options is missing under Product Information, and the About
>   button is the only option available, you either have a volume license
>   install of Office 2016, or your company is using Group Policy to
>   manage Office updates. Try Microsoft Update to get the latest Office
>   2016 updates or contact your company help desk.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you installed Office 365 from the Microsoft Store (or it was pre-installed using the Microsoft Store). In this case, you need to use Microsoft Store to update it (from the ... button, Downloads and Updates / Get Updates).

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me using Office 2016 16.0.4266.1001 Volume License was the following in Windows 10:

->Settings
->Update & security
->Windows Update
->Advanced Options

Enable `Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows`.
I was able to update to 16.0.5387.1000 and connect Outlook to Exchange online account.